# How to install ssl running Apache2 Ubuntu Webmin

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl

I have ssl installed for webmin fine.  if I go to my domain:webminsport it works great.
However is if I go to https://mydomain.com ssl doesn't work because it needs to be configured with apache.
I've done a lot of research enabled mod_ssl edited default-ssl file and added virtual servers, When I add the servers and restart apache it fails.  I'm missing something.  Any Ideas?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First of all can you let me know if you have installed Self Signed Certificate or Registered CA certificate.

Refer below link if you're using Apache Self Signed certificate

http://www.perturb.org/display/Apache_self_signed_certificate_HOWTO.html

Refer above link that will help you install certificate on Apache + Mod SSL if you're using Registered CA certificate

https://support.thesslstore.com/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=view&parentcategoryid=5&pcid=0&na=0

Comment: terrible answer. don't just link to things, actually put the answer here